# Notepad++ renumbering

Tags: notepad++, python, regex

Is there a way (regular expression or other option) to automatically renumber ID back to 1, 2 and so on like in example below?

```
<comment id="53" status="new">
<comment id="54" status="new">
<comment id="55" status="new">
```

To this:

```
<comment id="1" status="new">
<comment id="2" status="new">
<comment id="3" status="new">
```

I was trying to use Python Script from link in comment below. I have tailored it for code above and it looks like that:

```
def calculate(match):
    return 'comment id="%s"' % (match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))-52))

editor.rereplace('comment id="([0-9]+)"', calculate)
```

It do nothing. Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: renumber to what? subtracting 52? or do you need to start from 1 in each list? What is your range of numbers? ...

Comment: I need to start from 1 in each list. 53 is only example. It could be any nonnegative number.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506990/notepad-regular-expression-add-up-numbers

Comment: I was trying to use python plugin following instructions from thread you have provided. It does nothing at all. I don't know why. It only open pop-up window with two words 'Unknown exception' for the first time run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the Python 3.6 script. The file name would need to be changed and if the structure of the file changed in the future the regular expression might also require some tweaks but for now it should run smooth regardless of the number of lines in the file.

```
import re
file = open('my_file_1.txt', 'r+')
i=1
new_file_content=""
for line in file:
    p = re.compile('(\d+)')
    new_file_content += p.sub(str(i), line)
    i+=1
file.seek(0)
file.truncate()
file.write(new_file_content)
file.close()


# REFERENCES
# [1] https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html
# [2] https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
```

Comment: Finally I've installed Python 3.6.1 on Win 7 and run this script. Results are as expected. Thanks a lot!